# when in a cygwin, how can I display the windows folder where cygwin is installed?

Tags: cygwin

I am in a cygwin bash shell, and I need to find out where cygwin has been installed in windows, e.g. `c:\dev\cygwin`

I was hoping for an environment variable, something like CYG_WIN_ROOT but can't find anything appropriate.

Is there another way to find out where cygwin has been installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this do what you want:

```
cygpath -w /
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information, such usage is introduced in [Cygwin user's guide](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net.html).

It can be found under **1.6.3 File Access**

> The library exports several Cygwin-specific functions that can be used by external programs to convert a path or path list from
>   Win32 to POSIX or vice versa. Shell scripts and Makefiles cannot call these functions directly. Instead, they can do the same
>   path translations by executing the **cygpath** utility program that we provide with Cygwin.

and **3.1.9 Additional Path-related Information**

> The cygpath program provides the ability to translate between Win32 and POSIX pathnames in shell scripts. See cygpath(1) for
>   the details.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question.